# How to select from table which name is stored in a column with "0," prefix in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I need to be able to select everything from a table which name is stored in a column in some table with a "0," prefix.

I have a table in which there is a "argument" column that stores some different data. Some of those data are temporary table names with "0," prefix. For example "0,awfhe" and only "awfhe" is the table name. (Those are always only 2 characters on the left side).
But not every value in "argument" column is a table name.

I wrote a query like this:

```
DECLARE @agrtid   INT = 0
WHILE(@AGRTID<10) 
BEGIN      
SET @agrtid = @agrtid+1;
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

IF EXISTS (Select agrtid from awftrans)


SELECT @sql = @sql +
'SELECT
*
FROM awftrans A
JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(wf_table_name) + ' B
ON A.wf_group = B.wf_group
where A.wf_group IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
'
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT wf_table_name FROM awftrans WHERE agrtid = @agrtid
) t

IF @sql <> '' BEGIN
-- Remove the last UNION ALL
SELECT @sql = LEFT(@sql, LEN(@sql) - 11)

PRINT @sql

EXEC sp_executesql
    @sql,
    N'@agrtid INT',
    @agrtid
END
END
```

I want to use tables stored in "argumen"t column instead of "wf_table_name" but the "0," prefix doesn't allow me to. 
Another thing is that not every value in "argument" column is a table name.

Is there a way I can use "argument" column instead of "wf_table_name" in this query?

//EDIT:
 To be more precise, I thought of something like this:

```
  (...)
  FROM awftrans A
 JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(RIGHT(argument)-2) + ' B
     ON A.wf_group = B.wf_group
    where A.wf_group IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
 '
 FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT (RIGHT(argument)-2) FROM awftrans WHERE agrtid = @agrtid
 ) t
  (...)
```

//EDIT2:

The thing is, when I write a query like this:

```
 DECLARE @agrtid   INT = 0
 WHILE(@AGRTID<10) 
 BEGIN      
 SET @agrtid = @agrtid+1;
 DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

 IF EXISTS (Select agrtid from awftrans)

 SELECT @sql = @sql +
 'SELECT
  *
 FROM awftrans A
 JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(argument) + ' B
  ON A.wf_group = B.wf_group
 where A.wf_group IS NOT NULL
 UNION ALL
'
FROM (
 SELECT DISTINCT argument FROM awftrans WHERE agrtid = @agrtid
 ) t

 IF @sql <> '' BEGIN
   -- Remove the last UNION ALL
    SELECT @sql = LEFT(@sql, LEN(@sql) - 11)

   PRINT @sql

    EXEC sp_executesql
       @sql,
       N'@agrtid INT',
       @agrtid
END
END
```

I get a message like that:

```
     SELECT
       *
      FROM awftrans A
      JOIN [0,awfhe] B
        ON A.wf_group = B.wf_group
       where A.wf_group IS NOT NULL

  Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
  Invalid object name '0,awfhe'.
```

And I need to get rid off the '0,' prefix somehow within this sql statement.

Comment: you can use the `like` comparison, so you would use `like '0%' returns everything starting with 0

Comment: "wf_table_name" and "argument" in awftrans table. There are table names stored in both of them. I wrote the query above for "wf_table_name" column but it looks like I'm going to need it for "argument" column as well. The thing is that table names in "argument" column always have "0," prefix, for example "0,awfhe" instead of "awfhe" - correct table name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `LIKE` predicate to match the argument with the table name, so instead of `agrtid = @agrtid` use `agrtid LIKE '%' + @agrtid + '%'`:

```
...
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT wf_table_name FROM awftrans WHERE agrtid LIKE '%' + @agrtid + '%'
) t
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it is not what I meant. I edited the question to be more precise.

Comment: @KSiuda I still don't understand, can you please provide some samples of the arguments and the tables names.

Comment: "wf_table_name" and "argument" in awftrans table. There are table names stored in both of them. I wrote the query above for "wf_table_name" column but it looks like I'm going to need it for "argument" column as well. The thing is that table names in "argument" column always have "0," prefix, for example "0,awfhe" instead of "awfhe" - correct table name.

Answer (score 0):

The Above Query is correct only.
But instead of Quotename function use stuff function"stuff(wf_table_name,1,2,'')" to remove the first 2 characters which will give u the table name and in the if condition use 9 instead of 11 as length of union all is 9 only

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Could you maybe look at the edited question?

Comment: "wf_table_name" and "argument" in awftrans table. There are table names stored in both of them. I wrote the query above for "wf_table_name" column but it looks like I'm going to need it for "argument" column as well. The thing is that table names in "argument" column always have "0," prefix, for example "0,awfhe" instead of "awfhe" - correct table name.